# It is not possible to add the response from the API to the database

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

I have a Single GET request from the API. With `Retrofit` and `RxJava`, I get a response. Now I want to add my response to the `Room` database. But I don't want to use `AsyncTask` I want to use `RxJava`. I prepared a method in Dao insertAll. How can I use `RxJava` to asynchronously add my list to the database?
My get request:

```
@GET("contacts")
fun getContactModel(): Single<List<Contact>>
```

My Dao `insertAll` method:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertAll(contact: List<Contact>?) : Completable
```

My Request using RxJava:

```
val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

disposable.add(contactsRepository.modelSingle()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<List<Contact>>() {
            override fun onSuccess(t: List<Contact>) {
                // t - My List from Api
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            }
        })
)
```

Comment: yes you can keep common POJO class and fire the query of insert when you received data from an web api

Comment: You can use map operator and then insert all data in db

Comment: I don't know how to do it. There are no examples on the Internet

Answer (score 0):

If `contactsRepository.modelSingle()` is returning a `Single` Observable then you can just do

```
disposable.add(contactsRepository.modelSingle()
                   .doOnSuccess { data -> saveToDb(data) } // this will be called on Schedulers.io
                   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                   .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<List<Contact>>() {
                       override fun onSuccess(t: List<Contact>) {
                           // t - My List from Api
                       }

                       override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                       }
                   })
        )
```

If it is another Observable then you can use `flatMap`

```
disposable.add(contactsRepository.modelSingle()
                   .flatMap { data ->
                       saveToDb(data)
                       Observable.just(data)
                   }
                   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                   .subscribe()
        )
```

Comment: I need to save this to the Room database somehow

Comment: just create a fun `saveToDb(data)`  and use above mentioned process to insert it in the room database

Comment: what other fun? My date is the variable t . I can't add it before .subscribeWith (object: DisposableSingleObserver<list < contact>>() {
                       override fun onSuccess (t: list<contact>) {
                           // t-my list from the Api
                       }

Answer (score -2):

In java this is what I will first use Retrofit with RxJava and be able to retrieve Observable response from API as follows

In the Retrofit Interface service use the below code

```
    @GET("contacts")
    Observable<Contacts> getContactsFromAPI
```

in the @Dao Room Class implement

```
 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
 Completable insertContact(List<Contact> contact);
```

To retrieve the observable data items from the API use the below code

```
    RetrofitService getContactService = RetroInstance.getService();
    Observable<Contact> apiData = 
     getContactService.getContactsFromAPI();

     compositeDisposable.add(apiData
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
               .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Contact>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Contact> contact) {
                    newContact(contact)
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The contacts are : "+ contact);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error: "+ e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {                
                }
            }));
```

To add the add retrieve from the api to the Room database then create a method called which is used to insert data to the Room database and this method was called on the code written to retrieve the data from api

```
 public void newContact(List<Contacts> contacts) {

 disposable.add(Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
        rowIdInserted = 
    contactAppDatabase.userDao().insertContact(contacts);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.d(TAG, "inserted successful");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "tHE new error on create the new user is: " + 
        e.getMessage());
            }
        }));
     }
```

I think that help

Comment: onSuccess is not override fun. This code must be executed inside the RxJava code